# Using BS4 I have an issue when scraping Trustpilot review dates

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Given my below code, I am failing to get the rating and the respective date.

I can get the rating, but not using .text. It gets this whole thing as result:

```
</div>, <div class="star-rating star-rating--medium">
<img alt="5 stars: Excellent" src="//cdn.trustpilot.net/brand-assets/4.1.0/stars/stars-5.svg"/>
```

Which means I have some cleaning to do, but I'm sure it is possible to get only the "5 stars: Excellent". Just not sure how to do so.

As for the dates, my "date = star.find("div", attrs={"class":"tooltip-container-1"})" line only gets me None values, and I am not sure why.

Please see me code, the HTML for ratings, and dates below.

My code:

```py
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}
#def get_total_items(url):

#soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, format(0),headers).text, 'lxml')
stars = []
dates = []
with requests.Session() as s: 
    for num in range(1,2):
        url = "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.boozt.com?page={}".format(num)
        r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

        for star in soup.find_all("section", attrs={"class":"review__content"}):
            rating = star.find("div", attrs={"class":"star-rating star-rating--medium"}) 
            date = star.find("div", attrs={"class":"tooltip-container-1"})
            #print(rating)
            stars.append(rating)
            dates.append(date)
        #data = {"Rating": stars, "Dates": dates}
        time.sleep(2)
print(dates)
```

The rating html from Trustpilot:

```html
<div class="star-rating star-rating--medium">
    <img src="//cdn.trustpilot.net/brand-assets/4.1.0/stars/stars-5.svg" alt="5 stars: Excellent">
</div>
```

The date html from Trustpilot:

```html
<div class="v-popover">
    <span aria-describedby="popover_o7e1fd7whi" class="trigger" style="display: inline-block;">
        <time datetime="2020-01-20T10:09:54.000Z" title="Monday, January 20, 2020, 11:09:54 AM" class="review-date--tooltip-target">Jan 20, 2020</time> 
        <div class="tooltip-container-1"></div> <!----></span> </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to get the rating value, like "5 stars: Excellent", you just have to read the attribute `alt` from the `img` under the `div` with `star-rating star-rating--medium` class

Then, to get the date value, it's a little bit tricky because the date you are targetting is loading by javascript. But you can get it from the `script` tag just above. Like this: `star.find('script')`

I did some update on your code snippet and here we are:

**CODE:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import json

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}
#def get_total_items(url):

#soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, format(0),headers).text, 'lxml')
stars = []
dates = []
results = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    for num in range(1,2):
        url = "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.boozt.com?page={}".format(num)
        r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

        for star in soup.find_all("section", {"class":"review__content"}):

            # Get rating value
            rating = star.find("div", {"class":"star-rating star-rating--medium"}).find('img').get('alt')

            # Get date value
            date_json = json.loads(star.find('script').text)
            date = date_json['publishedDate']

            stars.append(rating)
            dates.append(date)

            data = {"Rating": rating, "Date": date}
            results.append(data)

        time.sleep(2)


print(results)
```

**RESULTS:**

```
[{'Date': '2020-01-28T05:37:13Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-28T00:00:48Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T23:22:58Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T21:20:32Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T21:06:42Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T19:37:16Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T19:27:38Z', 'Rating': '2 stars: Poor'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T18:20:48Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T17:18:42Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T16:15:17Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T15:58:49Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T15:46:29Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T15:39:23Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T15:32:43Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T15:29:21Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T15:27:30Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T14:35:29Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T13:43:40Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T13:37:53Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'},
 {'Date': '2020-01-27T12:58:58Z', 'Rating': '5 stars: Excellent'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Ratings are there inside image tag and dates are there inside script tag. You need to get the text of the scripts tag and load into json and then get the key value of the json.

Use following css selector.

```
import json
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"}
stars = []
dates = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    for num in range(1,2):
        url = "https://www.trustpilot.com/review/www.boozt.com?page={}".format(num)
        r = s.get(url, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        for star in soup.find_all("section", attrs={"class":"review__content"}):
            rating = star.select_one(".star-rating.star-rating--medium >img")
            date = star.select_one(".review-content-header__dates > script").text
            date1=json.loads(date)
            stars.append(rating['alt'])
            dates.append(date1['publishedDate'])
        data = {"Rating": stars, "Dates": dates}

print(data)
```

**Output**:

```
{'Rating': ['5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '2 stars: Poor', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent', '5 stars: Excellent'], 'Dates': ['2020-01-28T05:37:13Z', '2020-01-28T00:00:48Z', '2020-01-27T23:22:58Z', '2020-01-27T21:20:32Z', '2020-01-27T21:06:42Z', '2020-01-27T19:37:16Z', '2020-01-27T19:27:38Z', '2020-01-27T18:20:48Z', '2020-01-27T17:18:42Z', '2020-01-27T16:15:17Z', '2020-01-27T15:58:49Z', '2020-01-27T15:46:29Z', '2020-01-27T15:39:23Z', '2020-01-27T15:32:43Z', '2020-01-27T15:29:21Z', '2020-01-27T15:27:30Z', '2020-01-27T14:35:29Z', '2020-01-27T13:43:40Z', '2020-01-27T13:37:53Z', '2020-01-27T12:58:58Z']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your for loop to

```py
for star in soup.find_all("section", attrs={"class":"review__content"}):
    rating = star.select("div.star-rating > img") 
    date_tag = star.select("div.review-content-header__dates > script")    
    date = json.loads(date_tag[0].text)
    dt = datetime.strptime(date['publishedDate'], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")
    stars.append(rating[0]['alt'])
    dates.append(dt)
```